# Can Amazon S3 act as Source to Kafka Cluster?

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-connect

Amazon S3 can be used as Sink in Kafka Cluster,I want to check if Amazon S3 can be used as a source to Kafka cluster.

Comment: You could use Nifi to list an S3 bucket, get the file content, and send it to Kafka Record... You could also do that directly in Java yourself... So to answer your question - *anything can be a source to Kafka*... However, helping you find a pre-written library is considered off topic for Stackoverflow

Answer (score 4):

Kafka Connect - [FileSystem Connector](http://kafka-connect-fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/connector.html) has supported S3 as Kafka source connector. But it's not an official supported connector.

This will consume from S3, and duplicate those records into Kafka local-HDD segment files.

Comment: Please explain the process to use S3 as a source in Kafka,I am unable to summarize from Kafka Connect - FileSystem Connector.Any further help is appreciated.Thanks!