# Can Kafka apache cluster works with S3 storage

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, filesystems, apache-kafka-connect

We have production Kafka cluster , while Kafka apache version is `2.8`

Total Kafka machines in the cluster are **21** physical machines ,

Each machine used the internal disks and disks are with **XFS** filesystem , disks on each machine are in **RAID 10** and total storage on each machine is 25T

OS on each Kafka machine is **RHEL 7.9** version

Until now every thing is working fine

Recently customer asked about to move to S3 storage

And we want to understand if any of Kafka apache versions can works with S3 storage

I must to say that customer doesn't care about the existing topics data on the current disks

So its like to install scratch Kafka cluster with S3 storage ,

Docs / related links:

- https://kafka-connect-fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/connector.html
- [Can Amazon S3 act as Source to Kafka Cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50127346/can-amazon-s3-act-as-source-to-kafka-cluster)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. "Tiered Storage" is the feature you're asking for, and it is not available in open-source Apache Kafka.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-405%3A+Kafka+Tiered+Storage

---

You can use Kafka Connect (or alternative tooling) to **consume and write** topics to S3, but Kafka itself still uses local disks for storage.